# Please does anybody have a PHP library or SDK for orange-api SMS Cameroon

Tags: orange-api

I am developing a PHP based web application and want to integrate Orange SMS API for Cameroon. I'm in need of a PHP SDK or library to ease my work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a PHP SDK for Orange SMS API on github

see here for the link https://github.com/ismaeltoe/osms-php

Comment: Thanks. Please does that apply even to Orange in African countries?

Comment: hello, please i have tried using the SDK but i have can't find my_access_token in my orange config page.  please what am i to use for this variable

Answer (score 1):

HELLO Nganyu Emmanuel please try this library: https://github.com/ismaeltoe/osms-php
this work for all African countries where Orange is based(Cameroon, Cote d'ivoire, Niger, etc.) am in cameroon and using the same. and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this SDK can be used for the SMS API Africa provided on Orange partner website

Comment: hello, please i have tried using the SDK but i have can't find my_access_token in my orange config page.  please what am i to use for this variable

Answer (score 0):

For your **access_token**, go to your corresponding app page : https://developer.orange.com/myapps/{Your App Name}

Then, on the dashboard, click on **Show**, and *voila!*, copy your header credential, and then go to this link to generate your *access_token* : https://developer.orange.com/support/technical-guides/2-Legged%20OAuth

Let me know !

Comment: Hi, i have not been able to generate that access token. I am trying to use the chrome postman app, but i cant find a good explanation on how to use the credentials from my Orange backend. Also i would love to ask if the Orange SMS can send SMS's to non orange numbers. Thanks already.

Comment: Yes, you can send SMS's to non orange numbers.

Comment: But, I cant get you, why cant you generate the access token, what is the blocking point on my method ?